# saving PID of spawned process within a Makefile

Tags: makefile, pid

I currently have a Makefile rule thus:

```
start:
    ./start.sh
```

which starts a very simple server needed as part of the build process.  I have another rule for stopping the server:

```
stop:
    kill `cat bin/server.PID`
```

here is the start.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd bin
python server.py &
echo $! > server.PID
```

NB server.py must be run from within the bin directory

I'd like to implement the functionality of start.sh within the start rule, I've tried numerous things but can't seem to get the PID.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I don't understand where you're getting stuck.
What's wrong with

```
start:
    cd bin && { python server.py & echo $$! > server.PID; }
```

?

You can also make the pidfile a target and dependency:

```
start: server.PID

server.PID:
    cd bin && { python server.py & echo $$! > $@; }

stop: server.PID
    kill `cat $<` && rm $<

.PHONY: start stop
```

Comment: "I don't understand where you're getting stuck." - $$! seems to be returning nothing for me I'll look again!

Comment: typical its working now! I cannot see for the life of me what I was doing wrong before! - Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the catch was that `$!` is a shell variable, not a make variable (such as `$@` or `$<`), and therefore you have to double the `$`.

Comment: no I got the double $ - I think I'd separated the commands rather than making it all in one concatenated command in curly braces...

Comment: What do the curly brackets do? Is that a `make` thing or a `bash` thing?

Comment: @baruch: it's a `sh` (and hence, `bash`) thing. They create blocks of code. In this case they are required because `&&` binds more strongly than `&`.

Comment: Thank you. And what is the semicolon for?

Comment: That is a syntax quick: the closing `}` must be separated from the preceded statement by `;` or newline.